# What's the purpose of classes with empty constructor and no reference to DB

Tags: php, oop, hydration

I suspect this kind of question had already been asked but I couldn't find anything about it.

Everytime I work on a new project I see code that is supposed to be following the last fancy rules about OOP, MVC or whatever but everytime I look at it it just seems to me that it violates even the very basics of the concept they brag about.

For instance here I stumble on a class that represents a "station" with around 60 properties, but the only property expected by and set in the constructor is the ID, and this class has no access whatsoever to a DB from which it could get the information using the ID...

So there are 60 setters, 60 getters and a bunch of other method.
What is the point of this instead of receiving in the constructor an array containing all the information, or an ID and a reference to the DB which would still make the source of information flexible.

Is it that "hydration" stuff and if so can you elaborate on the benefits of it ?
As for now it just makes it harder for me to debug and locate the source of the datas.

Thank you all for your time !

Comment: It would be helpful if you share the actual code with us